# ManyToMany, duplicate entry, table empty

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

Soo : 
I have my two tables/entities texts and groups which are linked by a manytomany relationship.
I have a form where the users fill checkboxes to assign a text into one or several groups.
I have a problem though it's getting me this error

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO texte_groupe
>   (texte_id, groupe_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [2, 1]:

Here is the core of the problem ( i think?)

> ```
> public function AcceptMediaAction($id)    {
>     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
>
>     $texte = new Texte();
>     $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
>     $texte = $em->getRepository('EVeilleurDefuntBundle:Texte')->find($id);
>     $form = $this->createForm( new ChooseGroupeType($securityContext), $texte );
>
>
>     $request = $this->get('request');
>     $form->bind($request);
>
>     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
>
>            $groupes = $texte->getGroupes();
>            $statut = $texte->getStatut();
>
>            foreach ($groupes->toArray() as $groupe)
>           {
>               $texte->addGroupe($groupe);
>             }
>
>           $em->persist($groupe);
>           $em->flush();
>           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('e_veilleur_defunt_gerer_medias',
> ```

Groupe.php

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Texte",mappedBy="groupes")
     */
     private $textes;
```

Texte.php

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Groupe",inversedBy="textes")
     */
     private $groupes;
```

formtype

> ```
>  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array
>  $options)
> {
>      // $builder->add('statut','choice', array('choices'=> array('nonValide'=>'non Valide',
>      //                                                        'Valilde'=>'suchValidation'),
>      //                                        'required'=>'true'
>      //                                        )
>      //               ) ;     //  , array("attr" => array("multiple" => "multiple",  ))
>
>
>     $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
>     if (!$user) {
>         throw new \LogicException(
>             'This cannot be used without an authenticated user!'
>         );
>     }
>
>     $builder->addEventListener(
>         FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
>         function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
>             $form = $event->getForm();
>
>             $formOptions = array(
>                 'multiple' => true, //several choices
>                 'expanded' => true, // activate checkbox instead of list
>                 'by_reference' => false,
>                 'required' => true|false,
>                 'class' => 'EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Groupe',
>                 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
>                     // build a custom query
>                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->add('select', 'u')
>                                                        ->add('from', 'EVeilleurDefuntBundle:Groupe u');
>                                                      //  ->add('where', 'u.id = ?1')
>                                                      //  ->add('orderBy', 'u.name ASC');
>
>                 },
>             );
>
>             // create the field, = $builder->add()
>             // field name, field type, data, options
>             $form->add('groupes', 'entity', $formOptions);
>         }
>     );
>
> }
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
foreach ($groupes->toArray() as $groupe) {
    if (!in_array($groupe, $texte->getGroupe()->toArray()) {
        $texte->addGroupe($groupe);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're the mannn, thanks. Any ideas why i have a duplicate in the first place by any chance?

Comment: well actually one checkbox is fine but when i check two checkboxes i get "Error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?"

Comment: I guess default method is setGroupe(array $groupe), your addGroupe method will create an array in this way: [ 0 => groupe1, 1 => groupe1] so it will try to add the same group (and id) two times

Comment: ps. I don't know how you want to manage element deletion from N:N association, your code seems doesn't do this..

Comment: i have standards getters and setters which are generated by doctrine:generate:entities command, addGroupe removeGroupe and getGroupes. Indeed i have only one checkbox group ( several choices of group per text )

Comment: To avoid the nesting thing : in_array($groupe, texte->getGroupes()->toArray(), TRUE).